# Display unique SQL records joined to other data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write SQL to retrieve a list of all Windows 10 devices in my environment, and whether or not they have Acrobat Reader installed.

I want it to return only one row for each device, along with a 'Yes' or a 'No' indicating whether Reader is installed.

So far I have:

```
SELECT distinct
    SV.Netbios_Name0,
CASE
    WHEN ARP.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Acrobat Reader%' THEN
        'Yes'
    ELSE
        'No'
    END as 'Has Reader',
    ARP.DisplayName0
FROM 
    dbo.v_R_System_Valid as SV
    JOIN dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs as ARP
        on SV.ResourceID = ARP.ResourceID
    JOIN dbo.v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM as OS
        on SV.ResourceID = OS.ResourceID
WHERE
    OS.Caption0 LIKE '%Windows 10%'
GROUP BY
    SV.Netbios_Name0,
    ARP.DisplayName0,
    OS.Caption0
```

The problem is this returns a row for each installed application on each device:

[image: SQL Results]

Thank you!

Comment: can you share your sample schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `DisplayName0` column from the `GROUP BY` (and also the `SELECT`). This should do:

```
SELECT 
    SV.Netbios_Name0,
    MAX(CASE
            WHEN ARP.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Acrobat Reader%' THEN
                'Yes'
            ELSE
                'No'
        END) [Has Reader]
FROM 
    dbo.v_R_System_Valid as SV
    JOIN dbo.v_Add_Remove_Programs as ARP
        on SV.ResourceID = ARP.ResourceID
    JOIN dbo.v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM as OS
        on SV.ResourceID = OS.ResourceID
WHERE
    OS.Caption0 LIKE '%Windows 10%'
GROUP BY
    SV.Netbios_Name0;
```

Comment: Ah! Beautiful. What is the purpose of **MAX** though?

Comment: Without it, SQL complains that I'm selecting a column that is not contained in GROUP BY. Is it just a hack to get around that? How does it work?

Comment: @JustusThane `MAX` is an aggregation function. And well, as you can see in the results you posted, you will have a lot of `No` values and one `yes`. By grouping by `Netbios_Name0` and choosing the `MAX` value between `No` and `Yes`, the result will be `yes` if there's one, and `no` if there's none

Comment: I still don't understand how MAX is functioning here. If I change it to
`WHEN ARP.DisplayName0 LIKE '%Acrobat Reader%' THEN
                'No'
            ELSE
                'Yes'`
I would expect the results to be exactly reversed. However, that's not what happens. Instead, it returns only 'Yes' for each row.

I'm glad that it works, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: @JustusThane you'll need to read about `MAX` and aggregation functions. If you change the  `CASE` expression, you can see that you'll get many `yes` values and probably a `no` value. What's the `MAX` value between a `yes` and a `no`?, since they are strings, `yes` is the max value

Comment: Aha, it finally clicked in my head. My case statement is returning either a bunch of `No`s and one Yes, or only `No`s. If there is one `Yes`, MAX will output that because it's the "biggest" string. If there is no `Yes`, then MAX will output a `No` because that's all there is.

Thank you for your patience and for helping me to understand!

Comment: @JustusThane yes, exactly that